# Searching for Value of Date Formula with Find Method (VBA)

Tags: excel, date, vba

A large program I am writing at some points needs to find a certain date (DD/MM/YYYY format).  I am having trouble finding this date, however, when it is the result of a date formula (specifically, '=EDATE(PreviousCell, 1)') in any given cell.  If I input to the code, say, "1/1/2016" (as a string), I expect it to return the first instance of this date, which is created by this specified date formula in some cell of my worksheet.

```
Dim Range As Range
Set Range = Sheet.Cells.Find(InputtedDate, LookAt:=xlPart)
```

This fails to return such.  Any ideas? Please share.  Thanks!

Comment: add `LookIn:=xlValues` in the find argument to ensure it looks at values and not formulas only. You also may want to put the date in as an actual date and not a string literal.

Comment: I always thought that 'xlValues' limited to only text items, I never realized that it actually covered formulas and their solutions.

Comment: `xlValues` searches in the cell value (formula result), whereas `xlFormulas` will search formula strings or values if there are no formula strings (for a given cell).

Comment: I see now. Thanks for your help.